# using native_contact_picker in Flutter returns phone number in reverse order

Tags: flutter, native, contacts, picker

I am trying to get a phone number of any contact in contact list and put it in to a TextField in flutter, I am using native_contact_pick plug in,
I am successful in getting any phone number, but my problem is some of the phone numbers are reversed and I dont know why ?

here is a code for getting phone number and put it into textField in.

```
    openContact() async {
  final NativeContactPicker _contactPicker = new NativeContactPicker();
  Contact _contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
  textEditingController.text = _contact.phoneNumber;
}
```

that code must return phone number, and it does exactly what I want, except for some numbers that are returned in revers order
for example i uploaded a picture:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the string contains some whitespace in the middle, so now you have `<LTR1><whitespace><LTR2>` and when you render that right to left it naturally puts LTR1 at the right margin and then renders the remainder to the left of that.

Comment: thanks alot, you were right. it was because of whitespaces, and I fixed it by using RegExp..

Comment: it's not working any idea I used native_contact_pick  after picking phone it doesn't return to app